# I'm new in python, can someone explain to me about this syntax?

Tags: python, syntax, new-operator, kaggle

i learn in kaggle and try to do their exerscise to detect some word in their list.
they give me this syntax in their answer.

```
def word_search(documents, keyword):
    indices = [] 
    # Iterate through the indices (i) and elements (doc) of documents
    for i, doc in enumerate(documents):
        # Split the string doc into a list of words (according to whitespace)
        tokens = doc.split()
        # Make a transformed list where we 'normalize' each word to facilitate matching.
        # Periods and commas are removed from the end of each word, and it's set to all lowercase.
        normalized = [token.rstrip('.,').lower() for token in tokens]
        # Is there a match? If so, update the list of matching indices.
        if keyword.lower() in normalized:
            indices.append(i)
    return indices
```

and i make this syntax:

```
  def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    """
    Takes a list of documents (each document is a string) and a keyword. 
    Returns list of the index values into the original list for all documents 
    containing the keyword.
    Example:
    doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
    >>> word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
    >>> [0]
    """
    pass
    list_1 = []
    for i,doc in enumerate(doc_list) :
        words = doc.split()
        normal_word = []
        for word in words :
            word.strip(',.')
            word.lower()
            normal_word.append(word)
        if keyword.lower() in normal_word :
            list_1.append(i)
   return list_1
```

when i run that doesn't give same answer. kaggle answer give indices = [1] and my own list_1 = [0]

what is the different between two syntax?

Comment: do you know what is the pass keyword inside your code??

Comment: Should not the answer be [0, 2] since `Casinoville` also contains `casino`

Comment: mr bhavya the pass keyword that means casino in this syntax?

Comment: The output `[1]` seems wrong. [0] seems correct as it is the first element that has the keyword

Comment: okay thank you mr sid